# Embedded library in multi targeting .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, csproj

I have a .NET project that has 2 target frameworks: netstandard1.6 and net40. I am trying to embedded a libraries (ICU4N and J2N) that has target on netstandard1.3 and net40.

I created a `...\lib\` folder where I put .dll libraries for the corresponding targets.

My .csprog file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <SignAssembly>True</SignAssembly>
    <DelaySign>False</DelaySign>
    <DocumentationFile>$(TargetDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\someName.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net40</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1591;1570;1572;1573;1574;1580;1584;1658</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>

  ...

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1" />

    <Reference Include="ICU4N, Version=60.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=efb17c8e4f0e291b">
      <HintPath>lib\ICU4N\netstandard1.3\ICU4N.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="J2N, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f39447d697a969af">
      <HintPath>lib\J2N\netstandard1.3\J2N.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40' ">
    <Reference Include="ICU4N, Version=60.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=efb17c8e4f0e291b">
      <HintPath>lib\ICU4N\net40\ICU4N.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="J2N, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f39447d697a969af">
      <HintPath>lib\J2N\net40\J2N.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I run the program,

> `System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

error is issued, this error appears due to the fact that files `...\bin\Debug\net40\ICU4N.dll` and `...\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\ICU4N.dll` are the same, but should be different.

The question is how to configure the project and .csproj file so that during build the version of the netstandard1.3 library falls into the folder `...\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\`, and net40 version of the library into folder `...\bin\Debug\net40\`, because now the net40 version of the library falls into folder `...\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\` and `...\bin\Debug\net40\`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `HintPath`, the first found library was embedded.

Decision:
Add the following code for netstanard1.6 target block.

```
    <None Remove="lib\ICU4N\net40\ICU4N.dll" />
    <None Remove="lib\J2N\net40\J2N.dll" />
```

Comment: Also note that all the dll files are likely referenced as None or Content items - this will also cause them to show up in the VS solution explorer. If you exclude them from the project via the VS UI this should also help with the problem - MSBuild also considers None and Content items for assembly resolution.

Comment: Thank you, I will take this into account.